# javascript array no repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, repeat

Here is the array I can access randomly for the ten values.

```
var numArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
var answer = numArray[rand];
console.log(answer);
```

However, it repeats the same value sometimes. How do I ensure that the display value doesn't repeat consecutively?

Comment: Well if it didn't have a chance to be the same number twice in a row it wouldn't be random would it?

Comment: you coud splice the array each time you pick a number, and decrement the amount of random each time also.

Comment: IN general, sort the array randomly and take them one at a time.

Comment: if you want to have always the unique result, one case is to remove the selected index from the array

Comment: As Albzi said - if you want it to give a different number each time, you're asking for a different solution. The simplest way is to remove the entry when you 'read' it, and instead of Math.random()*10, use Math.random()*numArray.length. With the simplicity of this example I imagine this is programming homework, though.

Comment: what is the point of such task? want to accumulate randomely picked items - use `Set` object to obtain unique list

Comment: It is not necessarily an exact answer since OP might want 10 random numbers that do not repeat consecutively as he said - so 1,2,3,4,3,2,1,2,3,1 might be ok but 1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 is not. PS: thirdEye is member for 2 years